# Two bags each containing some MD5 16-byte values: how to know if the bags hold the same contents?

Tags: c#, md5

I have two bags each containing an indeterminate number of MD5 16-byte values.  Apart from visiting each bag in turn and checking to see if the other bag has each of its items, can the values be summed or hashed or otherwise computed in a manner that would let one quickly determine whether the two bags hold the same contents?

Comment: By "bags", do you mean "a folder" or "group of files"?

Comment: Of course not. How would that be possible without leaving open the possibility of an incorrect result? However, if you expect the bags to *not* be equal you could design the comparison in such a manner that it would reach the "unequal" result as soon as possible.

Comment: @Jon: how would you go about reaching the unequal result as soon as possible?

Comment: @gunr2171: By bag I mean a container with items in no particular order.

Comment: By "bags" I think he means arrays, am I right?

Comment: @John, my only thought was if it was files, you could "zip" them up to get the MD5 of the single zip file, if you get around meta data that could be added.

Comment: It's simple: If the counts of the two bags match and you can find each item from one bag in the other, they are the same. There is no shortcut, unless you track the items as you add them to the bag, in which case you can create some sort of checksum of the values and use the checksum and count.

Comment: If the counts are different I know they're not the same, of course; but assuming the count is the same, I'm interested in the checksum approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a helper dictionary with MD5 values as keys and simple two-flag structure or two-flag int value. Populate this helper dictionary with contents of both "bags", taking care to preserve information when traversing the second "bag". After that you can use the dictionary in all sort of ways.